# How to collapse the space above a pie chart and below the axis title in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For some reason, I'm getting a huge space between a pair of pie charts and their titles.  I'm not sure what's controlling this spacing.

I would like to collapse this space. At the least, can we center the pie inside the space?

Here is some sample code similar to what I am actually doing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1.1, 3.5, 2.2]
y1_sizes = y
y2_sizes = y

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1 = axarr[0]
ax2 = axarr[1]

ax1.pie(y1_sizes, shadow=True, startangle=90, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax1.axis('equal')
ax1.set_title('Old Stuff')

ax2.pie(y2_sizes, shadow=True, startangle=90, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax2.axis('equal') 
ax2.set_title('New Stuff')

lgd1 = ax1.legend(x, loc='lower center')
lgd2 = ax2.legend(x, loc='lower center')

fig.suptitle('My Chart Title', fontweight='bold')
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: The pies are centered in the figure. You can make the figure shallower if you want.

Comment: Is there a way to move down the axis titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering your question in the comments: "Is there a way to move down the axis titles?". You can achieve this by specifying the vertical location for respective titles in fractional coordinates using the parameter `y`.

```
ax1.set_title('Old Stuff', y=0.8)
ax2.set_title('New Stuff', y=0.8)
fig.suptitle('My Chart Title', fontweight='bold', y=0.85)
```

[image]